# Custom radio button in Xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a section where user selects a gender.
It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmbY5.jpg).
However, I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxn4x.jpg).
I researched, but could not find the solution.
How can I get this design?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be very easy to do using ToggleButtons instead of RadioButtons. You could just use a compound drawable in the button label.